# Programmatically selecting item in Dashcode list

Tags: javascript, list, dashcode

Is their a way to programmatically select an item in a dashcode list with having the user click on the list? Something like:

```
var list = document.getElementById("list");
    list.select_item(3);
```

Comment: This is pertaining to the edge to edge lists component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's just an HTML drop-down list (a "select" tag), then you can just set the "selectedIndex" property:

```
var list = document.getElementById("list");
list.selectedIndex = 3;
```